# Can you force a device to use a particular driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, mouse, touchpad

My trackpad does not work with Ubuntu 20.04.  It is recognized in xinput but it doesn't do anything when I use proprietary NVIDIA drivers.  However, usb mouse works great.  How can I force the trackpad to be recognized as a usb mouse?

Comment: Have you tried installing the NVIDIA drivers from the graphics-drivers PPA?  https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: I have not tried that.  How are they different from the pre-loade drivers or the drivers downloaded directly from NVIDIA?  Also, I think the trackpad is being recognized as a touchscreen.

Comment: From the PPA they are tested before they get released into the PPA for installation so they know the driver will work. Plus, they update with the kernels etc so you are not stuck with a driver that doesn't work if a kernel gets updated. As far as the trackpad goes, I am not sure how to do that since I don't have any of my laptops working with Ubuntu on them at this time.

Comment: I will give this a try but I am not holding my breath.  After researching my laptop with Ubuntu, I've found that this is a common issue with no apparent resolution.  Apparently, everything worked well for people until a kernel upgrade in 18.04 sometime.  Then trackpads stopped working.  I can get it working again by changing my display settings in BIOS but then I experience some other problems with the NVIDIA driver(s).  I'm afraid I might be stuck purchasing a usb trackpad.